# How does a non-capturing group deal with white space?

Tags: java, regex

I want to delete  whitespace character between **/>** and **<**, 
after read this [What is a non-capturing group? What does (?:) do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do)
 , I used the pattern like this `(?<=\\>)(\\s*\r?\n?)(?=\\<)`. But I found when I used the pattern like this `(?<=\\>)(?:\\s*\r?\n?)(?=\\<)`, it can also work well. Here is my test case :

```
<a>asdfdsf</a> \n     <b> hahaha <b/>     <a>asdfdsf</a> \n     <b> hahaha <b/>   <a>asdfdsf</a> \n     <b> hahaha <b/>

s.replaceAll("(?<=\\>)(?:\\s*\r?\n?)(?=\\<)", "")
s1.replaceAll("(?<=\\>)(\\s*\r?\n?)(?=\\<)", "")
```

and I got the result :

```
<a>asdfdsf</a><b> hahaha <b/><a>asdfdsf</a><b> hahaha <b/><a>asdfdsf</a><b> hahaha <b/>
```

after used the 2 patterns above.

How does **(?:\s*\r?\n?)(?=\<)** work? Why they have the same result?

Comment: In addition, you should probably avoid using regex to parse HTML content.  Use an HTML/DOM parser instead.

Comment: Sorry that your question was marked as a duplicate. Basically the answer is that they do the same thing because you're not using capture groups. Capture groups won't affect whether a given segment of text is a match. They are used for querying specific parts of matches. But all you're doing is deleting anything that matches, so they both work.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen just like i said, after read that answer, I have this pattern, the main point is I thik the first way is wrong, but it still have the same result.

Comment: There is _no_ functional difference between those two patterns, because you don't use the capture groups, you just replace with empty string.

Comment: I guess the title should have been "why do replaceAll replace characters, even when they are in a non-capturing group". To actually try to answer the question it will replace everything that matches (and a non-capturing group is also a match) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: @Marcus It looks like only **?:** can be replaced, **?<=** and **?=** will not work.

Comment: @MChen lookarounds (like `?<=` and `?=`) do not consume characters, they just assert if match is possible